# Unable to create mega menu using react bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a mega menu with react bootstrap where i have dynamic data coming from back-end due to which i do not know how many items i will have. I want to be able to show the data column wise and wrap the remaining data in next column and so on..I'm not able to adjust the width of the mega menu based on number of items and also i want to highlight color on odd/even columns.

`CategoryDropdown.js`

```
function CategoryDropdown() {
  return (
    <>
      {categories.map((parent, index1) => {
        return (
          <NavDropdown title={parent.name} key={index1}>
            <div className="category-dropdown">
              {parent.children.map((category, index2) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <NavDropdown.Header>{category.name}</NavDropdown.Header>
                    {category.children.map((subcategory, index3) => {
                      return (
                        <NavDropdown.Item
                          key={index3}
                          className={`sub-category`}
                          href={subcategory.slug}
                        >
                          {subcategory.name}
                        </NavDropdown.Item>
                      );
                    })}
                    <NavDropdown.Divider className="dropdown-divider" />
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </NavDropdown>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the css i have
`CategoryDropdown.css`

```
.category-dropdown {
    max-height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-x: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

.sub-category {  
    width: max-content;
}

.dropdown-divider {
    width: 40%;
}
```

My json response will look like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "def",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "xyz",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The [link](https://imgur.com/a/TUETuRO) contains what is expected and what i've tried.